# how to change supports disabled attribute to true in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabled button with a alert is clickable in IE8 (browser compatibility Issue in Asp.net website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521688/disabled-button-with-a-alert-is-clickable-in-ie8-browser-compatibility-issue-in)

[image]

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_DeleteUser" ToolTip="Delete User" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this User?')">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Img_del" src="Styles/Images/icon_delete.png" OnClick="imgbtn_UserDeleteClick"
                                        runat="server" Style="border-style: none" alt="Delete User" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to disable the link button and image button for certain condition, but I am not able to disable the link button because when debugging I found the supports disabled attribute is false. because of that in IE8 the image is disable but the link button is not disabled and I am able to get the confirm popup.

this is the source code from browser

```
<a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this User?&#39;);"  id="ctl00_MainContent_UserTable_ctl02_lnk_DeleteUser" title="Delete User"  class="aspNetDisabled"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$UserTable$ctl02 $Img_del" id="ctl00_MainContent_UserTable_ctl02_Img_del" disabled="disabled"  title="You don&#39;t have permission to delete users" class="aspNetDisabled"  src="Styles/Images/icon_delete.png" alt="Delete User" src=""  style="border-style: none" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This control does not support the disabled attribute.
You cannot magically tell it to support this attribute.

In particular, HTML does not have a `disabled` attribute for links.

Comment: Use a server-side `if` to set the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Img_del" runat="server" Text="Delete" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/icon_delete.png"
                                AlternateText="Delete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' OnClick="imgbtn_UserDeleteClick"/>
```

I solved it by using pop up in Image button [Learnt a new thing that HTML does not have a disabled attribute for links]